# When calculating theoretical futuresprices for oil, how do you calculate the storage costs?

Tags: futures, wacc

I have read that the terminal cost can typically be 0,15-0,5 dollars per barrel, but are you also supposed to include the cost of capital (WACC) when calculating the total cost? Why? Why not?

Answer (score 2):

The theoretical futures cost would be spot price plus funding cost, i.e. WACC (that of the average market participant, not yours), plus the cost of storage, plus the cost of taking the oil out of storage and bringing it to the point of delivery, minus any economic benefits that accrue from holding a long position of the commodity